# DocuSign NodeJs SDK: How to replace a document in an envelope which is already sent but not signed by any parties

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

My application dynamically generates a contract (PDF) on the fly, then it sends the doc to DocuSign and creates the envelope with the status sent.

Now I am in a situation where I want to correct the document. Is it possible after an envelope is sent? How can I achieve that?

I am using DocuSign SDK for NodeJs(docusign-esign).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to correct an envelope after it has already been sent, but not if the envelope is already completed or voided.

The following blog post will walk you through the process to make an envelope correction and also includes a Node.JS code example:

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-correct-envelope-your-app